# Retrying to read a file

Tags: java, file, error-handling

I have a piece code which retries 3 more times to open a file (see below). Are there potential problems or side effects with the way it is written? How can it be improved? Also, why would one use `Thread.currentThread().sleep(x)` instead of simply `Thread.sleep(x)`? Any other code smell exists here?

```
import java.io.*;
public class MyTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int retryCount = -1;
        String line = null;
        do {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    // try to open a file or stream (may not exist)
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt")));
                    line = br.readLine();
                    br.close();
                }
            catch (IOException e) {
                try{
                    // wait a few moment to see if the file or stream will be available soon
                    System.out.println("IOException occurred.");
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (retryCount == -1) {
                    retryCount = 3;
                } else {
                    retryCount--;
                }
            }
        } while (retryCount > 0);
       }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to be taken from: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread23935.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't ever call `Thread.currentThread().sleep(...)`.  `sleep(...)` is a static method on Thread and it's only because of some syntactic peculiarities that you can invoke static methods from an instance to begin with.  `Thread.sleep(...)` is idiomatic.

Second, I wouldn't set `retryCount` to -1, set it to 3, and then count down again to 0.  Why not just start at 0 and count up to 3 when necessary?  As a bonus, then your variable name will actually describe what it's doing.

Third, your `BufferedReader` won't close if an exception is thrown.  Either enclose the close in a finally block, or if you're using Java 7 or above, use a [try-with-resources block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

As a general case there's probably a better solution than just waiting to see if a file is magically going to show up for you to read, but it's hard to say what it is without some more specific details.

Formatting: Be consistent in your indentation and spacing.  Both are all over the place for both your try/catch blocks and neither match the (more common) style you use for the if/else blocks.

Comment: @MannyMeng, yeah. More credit for user3761894 and also to you for editing. :)